# BREW not working on Local Host PHP

Tags: php, sql, apache, homebrew, mamp

I am having some trouble using BREW on my local host server. I installed brew via Terminal on my Mac and installed FREETDS using brew. I have also changed my default PHP to the MAMP PHP.

Running which php gives:

```
which php
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/php
```

But it seems the packages I install via brew don't take effect on the MAMP PHP SERVER. I cant see the FREETDS driver anywhere in PHPINFO. Any help guys?

Comment: Are you talking about [BREW] (application framework for mobile phones) or [Homebrew] (OS X package manager)?

Comment: OS X package manager

Comment: And I'm using mamp pro

Comment: Thanks. I re-tagged the question to make it more discoverable. The `brew` tag is for an application framework for mobile phones; The one you were looking for is `homebrew`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here lies with me using MAMP. MAMP is not compatible with brew nor does it let me install extensions. The way I got around this was completely ditch MAMP and just go with PHPBREW which is a much more flexible solution and VERY EASY to setup. If you are going to need anything remotely custom (extensions etc.) go for PHPBREW.... it will save you so much time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try from terminal to run

```
php --ini
```

Output will show you loaded ini file for PHP client. Than you can try to edit that ini file and include additional PHP extension if they are installed.

If possible i would suggest to don't use MAMP, but some Vagrant environment.

Comment: What should I put in the PHP ini file as when I look at the folder the brew has created there are no .SO files in it.

Comment: Can I use brew with MAMP?

Answer (score 0):

If you type:

`brew info php`

You'll see that Homebrew is installing to a separate directory than MAMP (including extensions). You'll need to reconcile the two somehow to get it working correctly, but it may be worth it to configure your machine to serve from Homebrew's version instead of relying on MAMP Pro - otherwise you'll be moving files around.

Comment: But is it not possible to get BREW to work inside of MAMP PRO? If not what can I do to move the files into MAMP PRO PHP?

Comment: You'll have to build the extensions, find their locations, and move them into MAMP's directory or adjust your php.ini to look for the extensions. See: http://lkrms.org/php-with-freetds-on-os-x-mavericks/

Comment: Can I use brew with MAMP?

Answer (score 0):

use `MAMP` for one project or only certain specific projects.
and use the `HOMEBREW` directories however you set them up for other unrelated projects.

or use either `MAMP` or `HOMEBREW` to store backups of each other.

If you like and use `Mamp` export `mysql` and other files to your `homebrew` directory or vice versa. now you have an extra backup. On top of any other backups, you should have saved elsewhere other directories or hard drives internal and/or external